# Click anchor tag with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I click an anchor tag with a specific text?
Eg I have the following anchors in my page

```
<a>one</a>
<a>two</a>
<a>three</a>
```

Now, The user enters one. how do I click on the  tag whose text is one?
I tried this:

```
var uservar='one';
$('a [text=$uservar]').click();
```

But it doesnt work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I don't think there is a selector that checks it's text content.

Comment: you might add an ID to your anchors

Comment: You can use `:contains` but that does not use exact match.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu: Yes there is ..

Comment: @SyedQarib I haven't known it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

To select the anchor tag you can use jQuery `contains` selector. Example below:

```
var uservar = 'one';

$( "a:contains('" + uservar + "')" ).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter()`,

```
var uservar='one';
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.text === uservar
}).click();
```

`:contains` can also be used, but does not use *exact match* method.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/g5xkdja5/)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a contains selector that checks if an element containts a certain text.
This seems to be what you want

For example:   $( "a:contains($uservar)")

See the documentation for more usages of it: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( "a:contains('One')" ).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```js
$("a:contains('one')").click(function() { alert("One clicked"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>one</a>
<a>two</a>
<a>three</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Id for anchor tag like

```
  <a id="one">one</a>
  <a id="two">two</a>
  <a id="three">three</a>

  var uservar='one';
  $('#'+uservar).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

HTML

```
<a data-id ="One">One</a>
<a data-id ="Two">Two</a>
<a data-id ="Three">Three</a>
```

Script

```
<script>
    $("[data-id = 'One']").click(function (e) {            
        alert('Click event fired');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Give the same text inside the anchor tag  as data-id.